# The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again in orders grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, store-view, order-grid, stores

When I navigating to Admin dashboard -> Sales -> Orders. I am having this issue "The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again." I cannot able to see my orders list, I can able to see an order from customers view but not in orders.

There is no logs also related to this problem.

Help me to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Hello
Are you logged in with the main user ?

Comment: Yes. Of course.